# php multidimensional array problems

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, php-5.4

I want to output only 1 name data from my array which is:

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => some name
                [1] => Founder
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => some name
                [1] => Marshal
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => some name
                [1] => Marshal
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => some name
                [1] => Royal Knight
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => some name
                [1] => Knight
            )
    )

)
1
```

now I use :

```
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($API->getSearchFreeCompanyMembers());
echo "</pre>";
```

to print the array which seems to work fine but when I try selecting single array like:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($API->getSearchFreeCompanyMembers(1)[0]);
echo "</pre>";
```

all I get is 1 on the page

Any help would be much appreciated, if any more code needed please let me know.

Comment: How come you changed getSearchFreeCompanyMembers() to getSearchFreeCompanyMembers(1) ?

Comment: Can you explain what getSearchFreeCompanyMembers() does and how parameters affect output?

Comment: $API->getSearchFreeCompanyMembers[1][0]

Comment: You can accept one answer at a time but it's ok :-).

Comment: thank you all for the great answers been a great help

Comment: what if i wanted to do a foreach on names only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have changed the arguments when calling the method. `getSearchFreeCompanyMembers`

Your first example shows `getSearchFreeCompanyMembers()`
The second is `getSearchFreeCompanyMembers(1)`

To get the first element in the array returned by the method.

**1. Dereference as you did (just do not put 1 as argument).**

```
$result = $API->getSearchFreeCompanyMembers()[0]
```

*Beware the side effect is that the rest of the array returned is discarded. Also this feature is only available from <= 5.4*

**2. Save the returned array to a variable and pick the first element**

```
$array = $API->getSearchFreeCompanyMembers();
print_r($array[0]);
```

For more info on arrays and for dereference see example #7
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this

```
$array = $API->getSearchFreeCompanyMembers();
echo $array['results'][0][1]; // first name (Founder)
echo $array['results'][1][1]; // second name (Marshal)
```

Or, use (for `some name`)

```
echo $array['results'][0][0]; // first ('some name')
echo $array['results'][1][0]; // second ('some name')
```

Here, `results` is an associative array and the first array is `[0]` and every array (`[0]`, `[1]`) in `results` contains an array. So, it's something like this

```
$array = Array(
    'results' => Array (
        Array ( 'some name', 'Founder' ), // 1st array in results
        Array ( 'some name', 'Marshal' )  // 2nd array in results
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<pre>";
$members = $API->getSearchFreeCompanyMembers();
print_r($members['results'][0]); //no echo needed
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Hi, this answer came up for review as low quality. While I appreciate it's been a few years since you posted this answer, would you mind expanding on this with an explanation to help other users that may read this answer in future?

Answer (score 0):

like to print array results key [0] value [1] i.e founder. you have to call array like this
   before print_r there is no need of echo

```
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($results [0][0]);
        echo "</pre>";
```

similarly for

```
 echo "<pre>";
$employee=$API->getSearchFreeCompanyMembers();
print($employee['results'][1][0]);
echo "</pre>";
```